# Dynamic Image Generating in PHP from content

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

i want to know how can i generate image dynamically from content and also from existing image

as i know we can add sting to dynamically generated image in php

so actually i want to make image that contains existing image as well as content.

Comment: Related manual chapter: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 1):

Read through the manual pages about the [GD extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to learn how to use it to create and manipulate images.

But basically, to copy an image onto another, load it using one of the `imagecreatefrom*()` functions, such as [`imagecreatefromjpeg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) or [`imagecreatefromgif()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php), and use the [`imagecopy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) function.